# Airflow task not triggering when trigger rule ONE_FAILED fulfilled

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG on GCP Airflow with tasks like the below:

```py
with DAG(dag_name, schedule_interval='0 6 * * *', default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    notify_start = po.PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'notify-on-start',
        python_callable = slack,
        op_kwargs={'msg': slack_start}
    )

    create_dataproc_cluster = d.create_cluster(default_dag_args['cluster_name'], service_account, num_workers)

    [assorted dataproc tasks]

    notify_on_fail = po.PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'notify-on-task-failure',
        python_callable = slack,
        op_kwargs={'msg': slack_error, 'err': True},
        trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
    )

    delete_cluster = d.delete_cluster(default_dag_args['cluster_name'])

    notify_finish = po.PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'notify-on-completion',
        python_callable = slack,
        op_kwargs={'msg': slack_finish},
        trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    notify_start >> create_dataproc_cluster >> [assorted dataproc tasks >> delete_cluster >> notify_on_fail >> notify_finish
```

The problem I am facing is if one of the dataproc tasks fails, the `notify_on_fail` task does not trigger, despite having the `ONE_FAILED` trigger rule. Rather, it spins down the cluster and sends the all clear message (`notify_finish`) Are my tasks in the wrong order, or is something else wrong?

Comment: There appears to be a missing closing bracket ']' at the end of your downstream/upstream definition. Is that missing in your code? Or was it just missing from the example above?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @jdimella - that's not a part of the problem that's just me hiding all the data processing tasks :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expectation, I think the DAG should be like this

```
notify_start >> create_dataproc_cluster >> [assorted dataproc tasks]
[assorted dataproc tasks] >> notify_on_fail >> delete_cluster
[assorted dataproc tasks] >> notify_finish >> delete_cluster
```